# Does the space of hyperplanes in the Grassmannian have a name?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, terminology, grassmannians, affine-grassmannian

A way of defining the Grassmannian $Gr(k,n)$ is to consider the space of $k\times n$ matrices mod $GL(k)$ transformations on the rows. I'm interested in the space of $k\times 2n$ matrices mod $GL(k)$ transformations on the rows and $GL(2)$ transformations on adjacent columns.

Does this space have a name?

An alternative formulation of the question:

The Grassmannian $Gr(k,n)$ is defined as the space of hyper-planes of dimension $k-1$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. For example, a point in projective space is a 0-plane in $Gr(1,n)$ a line in projective space is a 1-plane in $Gr(1,n)$, that is it belongs to $Gr(2,n)$.

In this language, I'm interested in the space of $k$-planes in $Gr(2,n)$

Any input is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Is that $n$ different copies of $GL(2)$ acting independently, or just a single $GL(2)$ which acts in the same way on each pair of columns?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  If nothing else, this has the name $\text{Hilb}^{\binom{t+k}{k}}_{\text{Gr}(2,n)}$, i.e., the Hilbert scheme parameterizing linear $k$-planes in $\text{Gr}(2,n)$.  But actually, it seems to me that this is the partial flag variety $\text{Flag}(1,k+2,n)$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Gr}{\mathrm{Gr}}\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbf{P}}$Suppose you have a flag $W\subseteq V \subseteq \PP^{n-1}$, where $V$ (resp. $W$) are $j$-dimensional (resp. $(j-2)$-dimensional) projective subspaces. Then the variety of $(j-1)$-dimensional projective subspaces which contain $W$ and are contained in $V$ is $1$-dimensional and isomorphic to $\PP^1$. So we get a line in $\Gr_j(k^n)$. I believe that this gives an isomorphism from the variety of lines in $\Gr_j(k^n)$ is to the partial flag variety $\mathrm{Fl}(j-1, j+1, n)$. (The case $j=2$ agrees with Jason Starr's comment with $k=1$.)

Comment: @skd: You are definitely right that the space of lines in $G(j,n)$ (with linearity being defined by the Plucker embedding) is isomorphic to the partial flag variety $Fl_n(j-1,j+1)$. The reference I know for this is Buch, Kresch and Tamvakis https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306388 . However, I can't make this space match up with the matrix description in the OP's question. It looks to me more like they are considering a linear pencil of $k \times n$ matrices, and its image in $G(k,n)$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That's awesome, thanks for the reference! I didn't know about this interpretation of higher degree rational maps from $\mathbf{P}^1$ to a Grassmannian, but it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! Regarding the first comment of @David, Yes the $n$ copies of $GL(2)$ act independently. I'm trying now to get familiar with flag varieties and the Hilbert schemes. Many texts I find are very general on the field, while I'm just interested in the case where the field is complex or real numbers and in defining top rational differential forms on these spaces. Do you know any pedagogical books or lecture notes focussing on these aspects? Ps: I messed up with the upvote, sorry skd.